# version error in HIPI

Tags: hadoop, hipi

When I run tools`/hibImport.sh` , I got the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/hipi/tools/HibImport : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:153)
```

what should i do? should i need to upgrade my JDK?

Comment: :pls check updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, `UnsupportedClassVersionError` because java program was compiled on one particular JDK version(higher) and running on another version(lower JDK version) which is not compatible.

Fix could be pointing the symlink(unix/linux) to the version which was compiled if that higer version JDK already exists. Other wise you need to upgrade your JDK to latest by newly installing (Yes you are right in this case).

if you want to specifically find out JDK version of jar which it was compiled, you can tell the major version by looking at the manifest file. (you have to use `jar -xvf yourjar` to see manifest file content)

Tip : To find out java version command is `java -version` on linux shell(bash or some thing else)

Comment: thank u sir i have changed my Java_HOMe  variable to jdk-7 but i got the same exception again.

Comment: have you found out compiled version of jar as described above?